# How to optimize a mesh which I manually aligned

Tags: blender, mesh, meshlab, 3d-modelling, face

I manually aligned a mesh to another mesh. Two meshes have different topologies. The resulting mesh does not have a flat and smooth surface as is illustrated in the first picture.

My question is that, if there exist algorithms or tools such as a function inside meshlab or blender etc. that can smooth and optimize my mesh.

This is my mesh.

[image]

And I want to optimize it such that it is smooth like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the relation between "I manually aligned a mesh" and "resulting mesh does not have a flat and smooth surface". The aligned mesh should be similar to input mesh.

Despite that, try to apply the Meshlab filter [Taubin Smooth](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#taubin_smooth) to your mesh to rearrange the topology without introducing big deformations.

Comment: I aligned the mesh via Wrap4D. But the resulting mesh is not smooth, which looks like the first picture (see the closed eye, which looks like it has stretched triangles). So I would like to smooth the mesh (e.g. making the surface smooth, and making adjacent triangles have similar shapes rather than one is stretched while the other is compressed)

Comment: Anyway, Taubin Smooth worked for my project! Thanks.